# What should be the correct way to write kinetic energy of this body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, angular-velocity

[image]

This is not a homework problem. I only want to check my concept. The solution of the question given in my book goes like this:

The angular velocity $\omega$ of body about its axis as shown in figure using rolling condition will be:

$$ \omega = \frac{2v_0}{R} $$

And so writing kinetic energy of body as:

$$ K=K_\text{cm} + K_\text{relative to cm} $$

Giving us:

$$K=\tfrac12 mv_0^2 + \tfrac12 I \left(\frac{2v_0}{R}\right)^2 $$

But I think since the centre of mass is also rotating about this axis:

[image]

Which can be found by extending the axis shown in original figure till it meets the ground and and drawing a line perpendicular to ground from that point (yellow one) due to this there should be an additional angular velocity $\omega'$ relative to cm frame which should also be taken in account.

Comment: There does not appear to be an additional axis of rotation you are speaking of. The ball is rolling with a tilt. Your expression for total KE seems correct. The ball has a translational velocity $v_0$ and angular velocity $\omega=\frac{v_0}{\frac R2}=\frac{2v_0}{R}$. Everything seems okay.

Comment: @josephh consider a ring rotating about an axis perpendicular to plane at a distance l>R now velocity of any point of ring =w×(distance from. Axis) now due to this difference in velocities the ring would appear to rotate about an axis passing through cm and perpendicular to its plane when viewed from cm frame

Comment: What i argue now is that in similar way there should be an angular velocity w.r.t. cm frame in the question i posted @josephh

Comment: I see your point!  Problem statement is confusing to me; how can $v_0$ of CM always be perpendicular to plane of figure; doesn't the CM rotate for P to move as indicated?

Comment: Yes the cm rotate about the yellow axis @JohnDarby